# How do I remove MQTT mosquitto broker?

Tags: software-uninstall

I'm unable to remove or uninstall mosquito broker. What are the steps needed to remove MQTT mosquitto broker in Ubuntu?

Comment: i installed by using terminal  sudo codes from the source of internet.

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install mosquitto
    sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients

 i installed mosquitto broker using the above codes...

Comment: now i want to remove the mosquitto broker from by computer.so i need commands to remove them..

Comment: So `sudo apt purge mosquitto-clients` should be enough. Make sure you type the package name correctly.

Comment: if you install it from a Repository, you can purge it with type `sudo apt-get purge --remove mosquitto*` for the include `mosquitto` package, `mosquitto-clients` package also `mosquitto-dev` package. if you want remove that Repository with type `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa`

Answer (score 12):

As  [Abu Ahmed Al Khatiri](https://askubuntu.com/users/856659/abu-ahmed-al-khatiri) comment in question, is working for me so here is the commands how these needs to run.

To remove all mosquitto packages like mosquitto, mosquitto-clients and mosquitto-dev below command will be used:-

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove mosquitto*
```

After this we need to remove repository type so need to run this command too on terminal:-

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
```

This works for me perfectly. So this may help any one.